# Voltage Divider returns incorrect voltage reading

Tags: voltage-divider

I have created a simple voltage divider circuit as shown below:

[image: Voltage Divider Circuit]

Using the simulator, I can see that the voltage measures in at 0.838935V, which is expected.

However, when constructing this circuit in real life, I seem to be only reading ~0.513V on my digital multimeter. This project was initially supposed to read the battery voltage on an ADC, but this seems to be the root cause on why it is constantly returning a lower voltage.

Any ideas on why possibly this is happening?

Comment: Your meter is loading down the circuit, in effect putting a mega-ohm resistor across the 560k. Try to look up the specs of your multimeter, and see how correct it is by recalculating the voltage divider with the additional term.

Comment: When I have a new EE or intern, I make them perform exactly this experiment and I don't let them go until they can explain the results.   I do this so they understand the importance of recognizing the effect your measuring instrument may have upon the circuit under test.  Sometimes you can ignore it, sometimes it's critical.

Comment: On the plus side, once you determine what the actual meter impedance is, you can easily calculate the actual voltage you would have got otherwise....   You're using an ADC so presumably you're writing software.  Just make sure you document where the calculation comes from so the next guy (if there is one) knows why your equations look weird    ;)

Comment: Awesome. I actually considered the internal resistance initially but didn't think it would have made a significant difference (which it did!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple. Your real voltmeter is not ideal thus, it will have an internal resistance around \$1M\Omega\$. A better voltmeter will have internal resistance around \$10M\Omega\$

So your circuit will look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZrSLi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And the output voltage will be :

$$V_O = 7.88V \times \frac{560k\Omega||1M\Omega}{4.7M\Omega +{560k\Omega||1M\Omega} } \approx 0.56V$$

Comment: Ah, me don't know how a calculate, and I don't have any mega ohm resistors in my junk box. My workaround is using small value resistors. So in this case I would use 47k instead of 4m7.